What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of including the initial level of the dependent variable in a first difference regression?
Consider the two following models
$$ \Delta y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_1 + \beta_2 \Delta x^1 + \beta_3 \Delta x^2 + ...  $$
and
$$ \Delta y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \Delta x^1 + \beta_2 \Delta x^2 + ...  $$
where $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1$ and $\Delta x^i = x^i_2 - x^i_1$. Let's say I want to understand the effects of changes in $x$ on changes in $y$ and am doing a simple OLS. Under what circumstances, is it preferable to choose the first model over the second and vice versa?
I cannot seem to find an exact treatment of the problem anywhere. Any hints/ideas are also welcome. Thanks.

Hi: I'm not experience with first differenced regressions but I see the idea. My question is, if it's really the case that you are interested in how , $x_2-x_1$, ( well more than one $x$ but for simplicity, I'll just think of it as $x_2 - x_1$) is related to $y_2 - y_1$, then why should the initial level of $y_1$ matter ? In fact, what you are really doing in (1) is $y_2 - (1-\beta) y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_2 \Delta x^{1} + \ldots$. But I don't think you would want that because you are then regressing first differences on what is no longer first differences.

Also, first differences regression seems to require that one choose what is the dependent variable and what is the independent variable. I would do it both ways because you could get inconsistent results. There's a similar problem with the Engle-Granger cointegration framework in terms of which to choose as which.

Hi. Thanks for the comments. I might be mistaken, but the reason I include initial $y$ is because I thought it would control for initial conditions and unobserved heterogeneity among the data points. When I run both models, I find that the coefficient on $y_1$ is significant, suggesting there is some effect. The $R^2$ is also improved when I include $y_1$. I guess I am not sure if I can rely on the coefficients of the first model, but the coefficient of interest is quite similar across models, although some other coefficients are quite different.

The problem I see is that including it makes it no longer a first differences regression. If there's observed heterogeneity in the response, maybe you want to leave it out $\beta y_1$ but use GLS to estimate the model ? Like I said, I have no experience with first differences regression but I don't think including the initial level of $y$ is the way to go because it changes the underlying theme of the model which is first differences.

Yeah I agree. I see that there is a negative coefficient on $y_1$ that is very significant showing that there is something going on there. I will try GLS but maybe some non linear regression could also be useful. Need to think about this a little more.
Thanks for your comments.

Hi: if $\beta$ is negative and not near zero, then it could be that the differences of $x$ have an effect on $(y_2 - (1-\beta y_1))$ which isn't out of the question. So, I agree that there might be something interesting going on there. As the model stands, it's linear so don't introduce non-linear regression unless you're looking to build a non-linear model. Good luck.
